# How do I change a specific css element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, web

Any advice would be much appreciated, I'm sure this is simple for some of you web wizards. Thank you very much for your time.

I have some css that is working to change the revealed portion of .png when a user hovers over  it:

```
.small_icons ul li.companyButton .circle {background-position:0 0;}
.small_icons ul li.companyButton:hover .circle {background-position:0 -56px;}
```

I'd like to then keep the position at 0 -56px when the user clicks on the image and switch back to 0 0 when the user clicks on a different image. This is all happening on the same page so I imagine I have to use a javascript onclick function.

I can't seem to figure out how to access that specific css element using javascript. I've tried:

```
document.getElementByClass("circle").style.background-position:0 -56px;
```

but that doesn't change anything. Is it because .circle is a child class of .companyButton which is a child class of .small_icons?

Many thanks!

Comment: That's not valid JS syntax. Very first step before even asking a question is [linting your code](http://www.jslint.com/).

Comment: Accept any of the answers please, will help you SO account in the long run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You messed with type

`document.getElementsByClass("circle")` is `Nodelist` ([object like array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList)). so you should loop through it, or use

```
 document.getElementsByClass("circle")[0].style.background-position="0 -56px";
```

to loop through you need

```
var circles=document.getElementsByClass("circle")
for (var index=0;index<circles.length;index++) {
  circles[index].style.background-position="0 -56px";
}
```

[more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_dynamic_styling_information) about dinamyc styling

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do

```
document.getElementsByClassName("circle")[0].style.backgroundPosition:0 -56px;
```

Read more about it [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp#background)